# finding an array in another Multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a simple snakes game using JavaScript and HTML5 canvas.
I have a Multidimensional array that hold snake block like this:

```
snake=[[1,1],[1,2]];
```

and set it on arrayMap using (`snake.indexOf([i],[j])!=-1`) then draw arrayMap on canvas.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < blocksHeightCount; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < blocksWidthCount; j++) {

                if ((snake.indexOf(i,j)!=-1)||
                    (walls.indexOf(i,j)!=-1)||
                    (foods.indexOf(i,j)!=-1)) {
                        arrayMap[i][j]=1;
                } else {
                        arrayMap[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < blocksHeightCount; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < blocksWidthCount; j++) {
                    Block = arrayMap[i][j];
                    if (Block!=0){
                        ctx.fillStyle = (Block != 9) ? colors[Block]
                            : "#bdc3c7";
                        ctx.fillRect(j * cubeWidth, i * cubeHeight
                            , cubeWidth-.4,cubeHeight-.4);
                    }
            }
        }
```

the problem is `indexOf` isn't working when I set array on it!
It works fine when I set indexOf("i,j") but i need it to be array.

please help, thx

Comment: [i],[j] is not correct syntax. Perhaps you meant `snake[i][j].indexOf(someInt)`

Comment: Try to call it as `indexOf([i,j])`

Comment: Side note: Consider setting the arrayMap points by starting with an empty array, then iterating over snake, walls, foods and set the containing points in arrayMap; so you do not search all three arrays for each and every point of your grid - and do not need indexOf at all :-)

Comment: i was wrote the code wrong here and i correct it, it not working still.

Comment: arrayMap is not empty it feel by 0 whit two for, it easy to have snake, walls, foods apart to change them easier.

Comment: @webNeat it won't work, because arrays are objects in js and therefore their equality is checked by reference. So if you create `var a =[1,0];` and `var b =[1,0];` and do `a === b` you will get false.

Comment: You are right @Elena . Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution :**  using `Array.map`

Each element of your arrays `snake`, `walls` and `foods` is an array with 2 elements. So to check if an `[x,y]` exists in one of the arrays you need a simple way to 
compare two arrays `[x1, y1]` and `[x2, y2]`. Comparing arrays directly using the operator `==` will compare their references and not values (Thanks @Elena for the remarque). A way to compare values
would be to affect a **hash** to each array and compare hashes. By **hash** I mean a number which is unique for each array of type `[x, y]`. That could be `x * blocksWidthCount + y` 
in your case and the code will be :

```
function getHash(x, y){
    return x * blocksWidthCount + y;
}
var blockHashes = snake.concat(walls).concat(foods).map(function(cell) {
    return getHash(cell[0], cell[1]);
}); // hashes of all blocks in one array

for (var i = 0; i < blocksHeightCount; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < blocksWidthCount; j++) {
        if (blockHashes.indexOf(getHash(i, j)) != -1) {
                arrayMap[i][j]=1;
        } else {
                arrayMap[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Solution** Changing the way we see things

Instead of looping over all cells and verifying if every single cell is a block which gives a complexity of `O(N * M)` (`N` number of cells and `M` number of blocks). 
We can do better simply by supposing that there is no block and then loop over blocks and mark them as blocks which is in `O(N + M)` !

```
function markBlock(cell){
    arrayMap[cell[0]][cell[1]] = 1;
}
for (var i = 0; i < blocksHeightCount; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < blocksWidthCount; j++)
        arrayMap[i][j] = 0;
snake.forEach(markBlock);
walls.forEach(markBlock);
foods.forEach(markBlock);
```